# Scintilla lexer help. Trying to save specific line information for later use

Tags: c++, arrays, scintilla

I am using scintilla's lexing capabilities and I want to do something a bit out of the box.

Please mind that even though i have a bit of experience in other languages I am a beginner C++ coder.

I am looking for pointers on how to save specific information about a line for later used.
The first idea that came to mind is to create an array and filling the corresponding array field for our line number, eg:

```
int lineOpt[];

...

lineOpt[20] = 20;
lineOpt[21] = 20;
lineOpt[372]= 75;

...
```

But something doesnt seem right here. I am not sure if this is the correct way to it not only because of the 'unlimited' size array i just created but also because of the 'gaps' that will be present.

Only a few specific lines will have those options set (depending on some text present in them) and again I have a feeling that this could be done another way.

Any help or pointers to some article would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need an associative container structure, not an array. Arrays are always of a fixed length set at compile time; you cannot change their size at run time. Your declaration `int lineOpt[]` is not legal.

Consider `std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int>` or `std::unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned int>`.